# Convert doctrine array to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to read a column of doctrine type "simply_array" or "array" in json?

My doctrine database is approached from another api and I want to read data from that api. However there is a column of type doctrine array that I want to convert into JSON.

I am unsure if there is a preferred way of doing this or I need to hack my way around it.

Here is an example of what is stored in the database as a doctrine array:

```
"a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:\u0022day\u0022;i:5;s:4:\u0022time\u0022;s:7:\u0022morning\u0022;s:12:\u0022availability\u0022;N;}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the format of PHP's [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) function. And the literal double-quotes in the string have been converted to unicode escape sequences.

You could do the following:

1. Fetch the serialized string
2. Fix the `\u0022` sequences (replace them with `"`)
3. `unserialize()` it to reproduce the array
4. Convert the array to JSON with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).